# How to add an RSS feed link globally to every page?

Tags: rss, themes, xpages

First thought was to include the link tag in my theme. If a theme can be used: which content type do I have to use?

If a theme cannot be used: where do I put the link tag?

Answer (score 2):

Used it before, sorry, didn't recall #facepalm

How to do it:
Place the code manually in the resource section of your Xpage/Custom control as you are not be able to compute the href value:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:linkResource rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"
        title="Oliver Busse - OSnippets"
        href="/#{javascript:config.getConfig().getItemValueString('pathSnippets')}/rss.xsp">
    </xp:linkResource>
</xp:this.resources>
```